# I am trying to cast the integer N/2 into double so that the floor() function can use it but the output is always a garbage value

Tags: algorithm, casting, floor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
   int T, G, I, Q;
   long long int N;
   scanf("%d", &T);
   while (T--)
   {
      scanf("%d", &G);
      while (G--)
      {
         scanf("%d %lld %d", &I, &N, &Q);
         if (N % 2 == 0)
            printf("%lld", N / 2);
         else {
            if (I == Q)
               printf("%lld\n", (int)(floor((double)(N / 2))));
            else
               printf("%lld\n", (int)floor((double)(N / 2) + 1));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I am trying to cast the integer N/2 into double so that the floor() function can use it but the output is always a garbage value

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not with casting but with the `"%lld"` format. Either use `"%d"` or cast to `long long int` instead of `int`.

Additionally, I'm not sure what you're are trying to achieve with the `floor` function? You could ommit it and the result would be the same... `(N / 2)` is already rounded towards zero. Perhaps you've wanted `(double)N / 2`?

Comment: No,  I was just curious why the floor function wasn't working. Thanks for the help :)